# update with max function

Tags: oracle, max

I have 3 columns which are in use right now in the table. 1st is max amount one can use, 2nd is the amount one has used. Now, I want the 3rd column to be the max(1st-2nd,0).

I am using `update my_table set availability = max(1st-2nd,0) where type = 'bill';`

But in a procedure, it is not possible. The main thing is I don't want negative value and I want 0 instead of it. How can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GREATEST function:

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET availability = GREATEST(1st-2nd,0)
 WHERE type = 'bill';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a denormalization, which is not good practice. We have to maintain `availability` *every time* we update either of the other two columns. This is likely to be way more expensive than calculating available funds only when we need it.

A better approach is to use a check constraint to make the implied business rule explicit. Consider this version of your table:

```
create table my_table (
    id varchar2(10) not null primary key
    , max_amount number not null
    , used_amount number default 0 not null
    , constraint check_available_amount 
        check (max_amount - used_amount >= 0)
);
```

Now we update Bill's account (I realise this is not quite what your test data represents but anyway...)

```
SQL> insert into my_table values ('bill', 100, 0);

1 row created.

SQL> update my_table
  2  set used_amount = 75
  3  where id = 'bill'
  4  /

1 row updated.

SQL> update my_table
  2  set used_amount =  used_amount + 30
  3  where id = 'bill'
  4  /
update my_table
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (APC.CHECK_AVAILABLE_AMOUNT) violated


SQL>
```